# Get json from request flask

Tags: python, json, http, flask

Client code:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5050/login'
user = "newUser"
password = "password"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, data={"user": user,"pass": password}, headers = headers)
```

Server code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():    
 if request.method == 'POST':

    username = request.form.get("user")
    password = request.form.get("pass")
    //more code
    return make_response("",200)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host = "127.0.0.1", port = 5050)
```

The problem is that my username and password are always None.

I also tried using:

```
content = request.get_json(force = True) 
password = content['pass']
```

and

```
request.form['user']
```

When I print the content I have: < Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5050/login' [POST]> .So I cannot find the json send from the client.

EDIT:

I did add json.dumps and used request.get_json() and it worked

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are sending form encoded data, not JSON. Just setting the content-type doesn't turn your request into JSON. Use `json=` to send JSON data.

```
response = requests.post(url, json={"user": user,"pass": password})
```

Retrieve the data in Flask with:

```
data = request.get_json()
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried executing the same code that you have posted and I was able to fetch values for `username` and `password` instead of `None`.

[image]

Comment: Did you use Python3?

Comment: Yes, Python 3.4.4

Comment: What version of python are you using ?

Comment: I was using Python 2.7.10. Now I tried with  Python 3.5.1 but I still get None for username

Answer (score 3):

My initial guess is that since you aren't setting the Content-Type header in your request Flask doesn't understand that it should be able to parse the data.  Try adding Content-Type header with the value `application/json` and see if that gets you where you want.

Another thing to note is when I hit my login page the browser sets the Content-Type header to 
`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and encodes the data as `user=asdf&passwd=asdf`

Comment: I added `headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}` but it is still not working

Comment: Are you still dumping the dict to a string with json.dumps()?