# React, Axios and Flask - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

I'm trying to post some data from my `react` component via `axios` to my `Flask` server, like so:

```
handleSubmitSeeds(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {userId} = this.props
    const data = {
      arabica: this.state.formSeeds
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/handle_seeds/${userId}`;
    axios.post(url, data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
  };
```

and at backend:

```
@seeds_bp.route('/handle_seeds/<user_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def handle_seeds(user_id):

    post_data = request.get_json()

    arabica = post_data.get('arabica')

    (...)
```

but i'm getting the following traceback:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A header with Content-Type **and** authorization bearer was missing. Once I did:

```
var headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
        }
```

and passed it like so:

```
axios.post(url, data, headers)
```

`request.get_json()` worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever you are returning from `post_data = request.get_json()` isn't returning the type of object you're trying to use the `get()` method from.

Try console logging the request object to see if you can see the JSON object attached to it.

Comment: no, [get_json](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json) is flask method

Comment: referencing this thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126956/get-json-from-request-flask

I think Axios automatically stringifies JSON on POST request so it may not be coming through as JSON.

Comment: I have tried passing `headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'} ` as well, to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the data via the form request.form.get('arabica')??. At this point, I just want to determine whether the data is making it to your request object on the backend

Comment: try passing like this `.post(url,data,{ 'content-type': 'application/json'  })`

Comment: ^_^ sorry passing headers  by this way `.post(url,data,{headers:{ 'content-type': 'application/json'} })`   https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases